# Can You Scale the Content of a WebView Control to Fit the Container

Tags: maui

I'm using a WebView control on a page in my MAUI app and I would like the content of the page (a video) to scale to fit the container size.  Currently it spills over and it's not obvious (or useful really) that a user would have to scroll the video up and down and side to see it.  Can the content be scaled to fit the container dimensions?

Here's a short example based on standard new .MAUI project.  This is the page markup:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiApp2.MainPage">

    <Grid 
        x:Name="MainGrid"
        RowDefinitions="50,*" 
        ColumnDefinitions="*">
               
        <Button 
            Grid.Row="0"
            Grid.Column="0"
            x:Name="CounterBtn"
            HeightRequest="40"
            Text="Click me"
            Clicked="OnCounterClicked"
            HorizontalOptions="Center" />

        <VerticalStackLayout 
            Grid.Row="1"
            Grid.Column="0"
            Spacing="25"
            Padding="30,0">

            <Border 
                Grid.Row="1" 
                Grid.Column="0" 
                Grid.RowSpan="3"
                Stroke="Black" 
                StrokeThickness="3"
                x:Name="WebBorder">

                <Border.StrokeShape>
                    <RoundRectangle CornerRadius="5" />
                </Border.StrokeShape>

                <VerticalStackLayout 
                    BackgroundColor="White">

                    <Image 
                        x:Name="CloseBtn" 
                        Margin="5,5,0,0"
                        HorizontalOptions="Start" 
                        Source="close_button.png">
                            <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                                <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="CloseButton_Clicked"/>
                            </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                        </Image>

                    <WebView 
                        x:Name="WebView"/>
                </VerticalStackLayout>
            </Border>

        </VerticalStackLayout>
    </Grid>

</ContentPage>
```

The only thing I don't have for you (since I can't add an attachment) is the close button png file.  This is stuff added to the code behind:

```js
        private async void OnCounterClicked(object sender, EventArgs 
        e)
    {
        //display the  container
        WebView.IsVisible= true;
        WebView.HeightRequest = 
          DeviceDisplay.Current.MainDisplayInfo.Height - 60;
        WebView.WidthRequest = 
          DeviceDisplay.Current.MainDisplayInfo.Width - 20;
        WebView.Margin = new Thickness(5, 0, 5, 0);

        //show the video
        WebView.Source = 
          "https://www.youtube.com/shorts/JSIqFdb4KQ8";
        WebView.HeightRequest = WebView.HeightRequest - 
        CloseBtn.Height - 10;

        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            await CloseBtn.RotateTo(180, 200);
            await CloseBtn.RotateTo(0, 200);
        }
    }

    private void CloseButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //hide it a
        WebView.IsVisible= false;
    }
```

When the video plays it is much larger than the viewport of the device.  I'm looking for a method or way to scale the content contained in the WebView to be 100% of the WebView's size.

Comment: How can we reproduce this problem? Could you please post some code snippets or a basic demo so that we can test on our side?

Comment: I just edited the question to include some markup and code that you can use to see what I mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean the space of the `VerticalStackLayout`  of your code?

I tried to remove the `Padding` and `Spacing` of the `VerticalStackLayout` in your code,then there is no such problem.

```
        Spacing="25"
        Padding="30,0"
```

You can refer to the following code I tested on my side:

```
    <Grid 
    x:Name="MainGrid"
    BackgroundColor="Red"
    RowDefinitions="50,*" 
    ColumnDefinitions="*"
        
   >
  
    <Button 
        Grid.Row="0"
        Grid.Column="0"
        x:Name="CounterBtn"
        HeightRequest="40"
        Text="Click me"
        HorizontalOptions="Center" />

        <VerticalStackLayout 
        Grid.Row="1"
        Grid.Column="0"
        BackgroundColor="Blue">

            <Border 
            Grid.Row="1" 
            Grid.Column="0" 
            Grid.RowSpan="3"
            Stroke="Black" 
            StrokeThickness="3"
               
            x:Name="WebBorder">

                <Border.StrokeShape>
                    <RoundRectangle CornerRadius="5" />
                </Border.StrokeShape>

                <VerticalStackLayout 
                BackgroundColor="White">

                    <Image 
                        
                        BackgroundColor="Yellow"
                    x:Name="CloseBtn" 
                    Margin="5,5,0,0"
                    HorizontalOptions="Start" 
                    Source="dotnet_bot.svg">

                    </Image>

                    <!--<WebView 
                    x:Name="WebView"/>-->

                <WebView HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"   VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"  Source="https://dotnet.microsoft.com/apps/xamarin"  />

            </VerticalStackLayout>
            </Border>

        </VerticalStackLayout>
    </Grid>
```